# The more buckets are allocated, the less the load factor gets

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases, countable-nouns, comparative

I was writing an answer on StackOverflow and came up with this sentence

> **The more buckets** are allocated, the less the load factor gets. (x ?)

It sounds a bit off to me because of *"the more buckets"*. *Bucket* is a countable noun, and I'm not sure if "the more" can precede it.

Apparently, I wanted to go with the "the more...the less" phrase. Specifically, I wanted to emphasise "buckets being allocated" rather than "a number of buckets specified".

I am not sure about this either...

> **The greater buckets** are allocated, the less the load factor gets. (x)
>
> **The greater the number of buckets** is, the less the load factor gets. (v ?)
>
> **The more the number of buckets** is, the less the load factor gets. (x)

Please, correct me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The **greater buckets** are allocated:
  As a sentence it's almost valid, "The greater the buckets allocated" would work, however the meaning is different. It would mean you're using *bigger* buckets not *more* buckets. Objects of variable size can be greater and lesser, to mean bigger and smaller, but you'll rarely hear it outside specific circumstances such as "Greater London".
- The **greater the number of buckets is**:
  Here you're using greater correctly for your intended meaning, the phrase is fine but it's awkward usage.
- The **more the number of buckets is**:
  Nope, though you could also use **higher** instead of **more** to make this work.

Instead of **more** and **less**, numbers are usually **higher** and **lower**. There are more buckets, but the number of buckets is higher, so the only real change I'd make to your sentence is to swap **less** for **lower** as the load factor is a number.

> The more buckets are allocated, the **lower** the load factor gets.